# Job retried after 1 minute using Hangfire with Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, hangfire

I'm using Hangfire, backed by SQL Server, with Azure Service Bus

My Hangfire server configuration looks like this:

```
var hangfireServiceBusQueuePrefix = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HangfireServiceBusQueuePrefix"];
var azureServiceBusConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureServiceBus"].ConnectionString;

var serviceBusQueueOptions = new ServiceBusQueueOptions
{
    ConnectionString = azureServiceBusConnectionString,

    Queues = new[] { EnqueuedState.DefaultQueue },

    QueuePrefix = (hangfireServiceBusQueuePrefix.Equals("MachineName")
        ? Environment.MachineName
        : hangfireServiceBusQueuePrefix)
        + "-hangfire-"
};

var storage = new SqlServerStorage("Hangfire")
    .UseServiceBusQueues(serviceBusQueueOptions);

_hangfireConfiguration = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .UseStorage(storage);
```

I noticed that if my job hadn't completed after just over 1 minute, it was being replayed - even though the original job was still running...

For example, when I queue a job like this:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(MyMethod);
```

and if we imagine `MyMethod` looks like this

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("MyMethod Started");
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
    Console.WriteLine("MyMethod Finished");
}
```

... what happens is, 1 minute in, the method will 'restart'
30 seconds later, the first instance will complete, then the second instance will finish another 60 seconds later.

I need this job to complete, without it being re-tried after one minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive a message, the message is locked for a certain duration. This is to avoid another receiver to get the same message.

You can configure the [`LockDuration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.lockduration.aspx) when you create the queue.
From the documentation:

> The maximum value for LockDuration is 5 minutes; the default value is 1 minute.

If you need to lock the message for more than 5 minutes, you can increase the lock manually using the [RenewLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.renewlock.aspx) method..

Comment: Slight snag is that I don't have access to the RenewLock method using the Hangfire Azure Service Bus library... I don't think?

Comment: The renewlock is on the brokeredmessage. Do you have access to the brokeredmessage ?

Comment: No, it's all wrapped up. I'll take a look at the source for the lib and see if there's anything I can add